# JavaPOS with EPSON tm-t88iii, Cannot Print

Tags: epson, receipt, javapos

My situation is the following : I have to develop a POS application for a take away Pizzeria, I have an EPSON tm-t88iii receipt printer.

I did : Installed the ESPON JavaPOS ADK , generated a jpos.xml file with SETUPPOS (HealthCheck works fine).

My issue : When I try to connect to the printer with the open method, I have the following Exception and I don't know why :

"jpos.JposException: Could not connect to service with logicalName = tm88: Exception.message=Could not create service instance."

With this code :

```
POSPrinterControl19 ptr =  (POSPrinterControl19) new POSPrinter();

try {
   ptr.open("tm88");
} catch (JposException ex) {
   System.err.println(ex.toString());
}
```

Here are my jpos.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE JposEntries PUBLIC "-//JavaPOS//DTD//EN"
                             "jpos/res/jcl.dtd">
<JposEntries>
<!--Saved by JavaPOS jpos.config/loader (JCL) version 2.2.0 on 23.06.14 21:59-->

        <JposEntry logicalName="tm88">
        <creation factoenter code hereryClass="jp.co.epson.uposcommon.util.EpsonJposServiceInstanceFactory" serviceClass="jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_13_0001.pntr.T88IIIService"/>
        <vendor name="SEIKO EPSON" url="http://www.epson.com"/>
        <jpos category="POSPrinter" version="1.13"/>
        <product description="EPSON TM-T88III Printer Device Service" name="EPSON Services for JavaPOS(TM) Standard" url="http://www.epson.com"/>

        <!--Other non JavaPOS required property (mostly vendor properties and bus specific properties i.e. RS232 )-->
    ........
</JposEntry>

</JposEntries>
```

I do find this weird as the HealthCheck From the EPSON ADK works fine and my example not. Of course, I did include all the librairies from the EPSON ADK to the Project. Has anybody an idea ?

Thank you

My specs:

OS : WINDOWS 8.1 64 bits
IDE : netbeans 8
Connection to the receipt : Serial

Comment: Dear friend, I have a Vega7000 Series  EFT-POS terminal. Do you have any idea how can I develop program for it? What kind of tools and IDEs and Documents am I need? Where can I find this requirements? And does it have JVM? i.e. does it support Java applications or I must use another programming language? Any light on this issue highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the printer with:

```
System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, "jpos.xml");
```

and load your `jpos.xml`  use `route\\jpos.xml`

this file is generated by the utility program.